# Copy Dynamic Range Using Offset in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy a dynamic range of columns using offset?  I have 2 defined ranges `ew_col_1` and `ew_col_2`. The user can select numbers 1 to 12 (months) so if they select 1 and 6, it would copy January through June sales below. If they select 4 and 7, it would copy April through July and so on.

I do not think I'm properly nesting my code below so any advice is welcome !  Can I nest a defined range inside a ranged offset ?

```
Range("A1:A2").Offset(0,Range("ew_col_1")),Range("A1:A2").Offset(0,Range("ew_col_2"))
```

[image: Sales]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Resize()` property, too:

```
  Range("A1:A2").Offset(0,Range("ew_col_1").Value).Resize(, Range("ew_col_2").Value - Range("ew_col_1").Value + 1)
```

Comment: Receiving a "Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed" error, trying to research it now.  Does it matter if my defined ranges are on a different sheet?